# Knot program crossing information

Tags: knot-theory

Is there a program where if I just give information on a knot-things like the crossing information, then the program will produce the knot?

Comment: Mathematica can do knots. Have a look at [KnotData](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/KnotData.html).